# LINQ To XML - How to query for all the elements in an inner element?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

```
<Results>
  <ResultSet>"nothing special" Description="More of nothing"
    <Results>
      <Result>
        <Body>Four in this group</Body>
        <Body2>this is more stuff I want</Body2>
        <Body3>This is interesting stuff I want</Body3>
        <Body4>this is more stuff I want</Body4>
      </Result>
      <Result>
        <Something1>Only 3 in the group</Something1>
        <ID>this is more stuff I want</ID>
        <Stuff>This is interesting stuff I want</Stuff>
      </Result>
      <Result>
        <Tag1>Only 3 in the group</Tag1>
        <Tag2>this is more stuff I want</Tag2>
        <Tag3>This is interesting stuff I want</Tag3>
      </Result>
    </Results>
  </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

How would I use Linq to XML to pull out all the `<Result>`blocks?  As you can see each block can have any number of elements and I won't know what they are called.  My end goal is to package these blocks up into objects that I will then pass around my app.

The issue I have is I can't get each group broken out seperatly using Linq.  The closest I can get is returning all elements within ALL the `<Result>` groups into one big list (using Descendants).

Edit:  This is the code I am using to bring back everything in each `<Result>` group.  I can't figure out how to iterate through list from this query to break out the name/value pairs.  I don't know the names of the elements, so I can't reference them by name. At the end, I just want the name/value pair of each element within each `<Result>`.

```
var query = from item in xml.Descendants("Result")
              select item;
```

Any help?

Thanks,  -Scott

Comment: `Descendants` shouldn't return things "inside" `Results` element. It should return a sequence of `Result` elements, and that's apparently what you need. What exactly doesn't work with `Descendants`?

Comment: I just updated the post to show the code I am using and what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descendants will grab all descendant nodes with the given name. If you want to be specific you need to walk down the XML hierarchy element by element, such as `xml.Element("ResultSet").Element("Results").Elements("Result")`.

This should point you in the right direction:

```
var query = xml.Descendants("Result")
               .Select(r => r.Elements()
                             .Select(e => new { Name = e.Name.LocalName, Value = e.Value }));
foreach (var result in query)
{
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Name, item.Value);
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can use `SelectMany` and flatten the result set:

```
var query = xml.Descendants("Result")
               .SelectMany(r => r.Elements()
                                 .Select(e => new { Name = e.Name.LocalName, Value = e.Value }));
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Name, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Your first example is exactly what I was looking for. This keeps the name/values grouped.  The second example is what I kept getting.  It's too flat to be useful since I don't know where one group starts and the other ends.  This is perfect.  Thanks!